# Plain text from a section in a view - Emails, Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, email, laravel

I'm trying to send a the input from the user, but I don't know how to send the text the user added.

In my view:

```
<div class="form-group">
   {!! Form::label('text','Съдържание:', ['class' => 'control-label col-md-3']) !!}
   <div class="col-md-6">
      {!! Form::textarea('text', null,['class' => 'form-control' ]) !!}
   </div>
</div>
```

And my controller:

```
public function personalEmail(Request $request)
{

    $user = Auth::user();

    $data = array(
        'name' => 'MГ "Константин Величков"',
    );


    Mail::send('?????', $data, function ($message) use ($request, $user) {
        $message->from($request->input('from'), $user->full_name);
        $message->to([$request->input('to')],'test');
        $message->subject($request->input('subject'));

    });

    return ':P';
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `$request->input('text')`:

```
Mail::send('your.view.for.email', ['text' => $request->input('text')] .....)
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/requests#accessing-the-request

Alternatively, you could try `raw()` method:

```
Mail::raw($request->input('text'), function ($message) use ($request, $user) {
    $message->from($request->input('from'), $user->full_name);
    $message->to([$request->input('to')],'test');
    $message->subject($request->input('subject'));

});
```

Comment: I can't just send some text  - got this `View [some random text] not found.`

Comment: Okay, and can i send only this section from the view? Not the whole view?

Comment: I've updated my answer. If you want to use just text without touching any view, try `raw()`. Not tested, but should work.

Comment: Please look at updated example. Did you try it exactly like this? I mean with just two parameters: text and callback (function part)?